# Trying to parse log file with regex

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

I am trying to parse a log file with a regex and I understand the first of pulling out the IP addressed but I am stuck on how to move beyond the rest of it for the log file. So to start parsing the rest do I just tack on the regex to parse out the date and etc?  So i would 2nd element to be the second ip of 72.37.100.86. Then I would like to exclude the "- - -" and have the date be the 4th element along with "GET / HTTP/1.1:" to be the 8th index along with the status code of 200 to be the 9th index.  Any help with this would be much appreciated in understanding what I need to do next.

```
package com.text.nginx_log_parser;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RegExTester {


// Actual Entry : 10.10.100.151 - 72.37.100.86, 192.36.20.508 - - - [04/Jul/2016:12:50:06 +0000]  https https https "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20027 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36"
public static String logEntry = "10.10.100.151 - 72.37.100.86, 192.36.20.508 - - - [04/Jul/2016:12:50:06 +0000]  https https https \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 20027 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36\"\r\n";

//public static String regex = "(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})";
//public static String regex = "(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})";
public static void main (String [] args){

    String regex = "(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})\\s*-*\\s*-*\\s*-*";
    regexChecker(regex, logEntry);
    regex = "\\[*\\]\\s.";
    regexChecker(regex, logEntry);
}

public static void regexChecker(String regex, String str){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(logEntry);
    //String firstIP = matcher.group(0);
    //String secondIP = matcher.group();
    //String timestamp = 
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println( matcher.group(0));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what output your expect from this string?

Answer (score 1):

With the following regex:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[-\s]+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+?\[(.+?)\].*?\"(.+?)\"\s(\d{3}).*$
```

you are looking at capture groups **1** through **5** as per [this entry on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AiaD0Z/2)